# Failed to process API response. Interaction.js Salesforce

Tags: opencti, twilio

I'm using Twilio-Salesforce API to generate outbound calls, I've activated ClickToDial in my visualforce, but when I'm clicking the call button I'm receiving 'Failed to process API response' error message.

[image: Error Message]

and this is my javascript code:

[image: javascript code]

Any one have idea why this error is fired?

Comment: Have you tried removing the whitespace from `{! token }` ?

Comment: I removed the whitespaces but still having the error message, curiously I added other function to formatting number, that is called from the startCall function and now is working. I'll post the functions as a Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the cleanFormatting function that is invoked from startCall function, here the three functions tht I'm using:

```
        sforce.interaction.cti.onClickToDial(startCall);//Invoke startCallFunction


        /*********************************
            Start a call to salesforce
        **********************************/
        function startCall(response) {    

            sforce.interaction.setVisible(true);  //pop up CTI console
            var result = JSON.parse(response.result);  
            var cleanednumber = cleanFormatting(result.number);             
            params = {"PhoneNumber": cleanednumber};
            Twilio.Device.connect(params);

        }

        /*********************************
               Clean Formating
        **********************************/
        function cleanFormatting(number) { 
              //changes a SFDC formatted US number, which would be 415-555-1212  into a twilio understanble number 4155551212      
             return number.replace(' ','').replace('-','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('+','');
        }
```

I hope it helps.